# Where is the '$router' variable defined in 'web.php' in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Can't find where the `$router` variable is defined in [Lumen](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/c25833addaff0db442614f7539d22d66fd1919fb/routes/web.php#L14) `web.php`. The content of `web.php` is just like this and it is not clear how the `$router` variable is defined:

```php
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
```

As you can see there is no pre-definition of the `$router` variable. Is it loaded here from another file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is magic :) if you open `bootstrap/app.php` which is what bootstraps the whole application and loads the routes you will see this code:

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});
```

So the `$router` is available in the `web.php` file as a global property.